# Can I change the color of the labels on my brackets, without changing the color of the bracket itself? (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm plotting some percentages of answers on a Likert-scale, and need to mark the sum of answer 1-2 and 4-5. I've done this pretty okay with the brackets, but I'm having some troubles with its colors. I'd like the bracket to be of the same color as the answering alternatives it represents, but I'd still like the text to be black. Is there a neat way to fix this?

Here's my code (a function for creating the plot I need with different questions and different percentages):

```
### FUNCTION
plot_function <- function (question, percent_1, percent_2, percent_3, percent_4, percent_5, percent_6) {
  
  # Create temporary df
  answers <- c(percent_1, percent_2, percent_3, percent_4, percent_5, percent_6)
  
  labs = vector(mode = "list", length = 6)
  for (i in 1:6) {
    labs[i] <- paste(toString(answers[i]), "%", sep = "")
  }
  
  df <- data.frame(Scale, answers, labs)
  
  # Create plot
  plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x=Scale,  y = answers)) +
    geom_bar(aes(fill=factor(..x..)), stat = "identity") +
    labs(x = "", y="Percent", fill="Scale", title = question) +
    scale_fill_manual(name = "Scale",
                      labels = Scale,
                      values = c(color_1, color_2, color_3, color_4, color_5, color_6)) +
    theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = 'grey',
                                          size = 0.25,
                                          linetype = 'dashed')) +
    theme_tufte() +
    geom_text(label = labs, nudge_y = 1.5, family = font) +
    geom_bracket(xmin = 1, 
                 xmax = 2, 
                 y.position = max(answers) + 10,
                 label = paste(toString(percent_1 + percent_2), "%", sep = ""), 
                 tip.length = c(0.05, 0.05), 
                 family = font,
                 vjust = -1, 
                 size = 1,
                 color = color_1) +
    geom_bracket(xmin = 4, 
                 xmax = 5, 
                 y.position = max(answers) + 10,
                 label = paste(toString(percent_4 + percent_5), "%", sep = ""), 
                 tip.length = c(0.05, 0.05),
                 family = font,
                 vjust = -1,
                 size = 1,
                 color = color_5) +
    ylim(c(0, max(answers + 15)))
  
  # Return plot
  plot
  
}
```

As you can see below, the labels for the brackets take on the same color as the bracket itself. How can I make the label black, while keeping the colored brackets? :)

[image]

Comment: `ggpubr::geom_bracket()` does not appear to have such an option, you could just move the label to a separate `geom_text()`. There you would have full control over its color.

Comment: How would I do that? The other `geom_text()` that I already have doesn't seem to be tied to the bars, yet they clearly are... Sorry, I'm just a bit confused!